# Javascript files are not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-status-code-404

I'm new to Angular JS , trying to develop little application on Calculations .
My Code is as follows"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="Calculator">
        <div ng-controller="Operations">
            <div>
                Number 1 : <input type="number" ng-model="Number1" />
                Number 2: <input type="number" ng-model="Number2" />
                <p>
                    The addition of above two numbers is {{Number1+Number2}}
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var module = angular.module('Calculator', []);
        module.controller('Operations', function ($scope) {
            $scope.Number1 = 1;
            $scope.Number2 = 10;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the Javascripts files available in My project, When  I run the app, the browser console indicates that the JS are not being loaded. Don't know why !
The Expression {{Number1+Number2}} is the same in browser . It is not executing the expression

The Browser console has following errors:

> Failed to load resource:"Path to the Script file" the server responded with a 
>   status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> Failed to load resource:"Path to the Script file" the server responded with a 
>   status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Comment: That means the path is wrong. Make sure you have a "scripts" folder in the same folder as your HTML file that has "angular.js" and "angular-route.js".

Comment: what is the path the error shows? that's where its looking...

Comment: Hey @MikeC, You're right. I dragged the files onto my htmlpage . But the auto generated path of the script files is wrong. I add "/" before the path which fixed the error. Thanks

Comment: to make it (relative path) clear and to be confident linking any web resource in future, spend 2 - 5 minute here https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
```

You are not loading angular.js and angular-route.js properly, check your paths.

Comment: I add "/" before the path which fixed the error. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your project structure has to look like

```
index.html
scripts
    |---angular.js
    |---angular-route.js
```

If you use

```
<script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Comment: I add "/" before the path which fixed the error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="/scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Please note , you might need to disable adblocks if necessary.
Drag and drop in visual studio doesn't work if you are using HTML pages but it does work for mvc ,asp.netwebforms.
I figured this after one hour